# Make Class Library compatible to DNX Core 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to create my first ASP.NET 5 Web Api project. I need to add a previously create class library as a reference. So I go References -> Add reference and add the appropriate project. Unfortunately the reference is still unresolved.

Seems like it happens cause the reference goes to DNX 4.5.1 but not DNX Core 5.0. And in project.json it goes not to root `dependencies` but to frameworks:

```
"frameworks": {
        "dnx451": {
            "dependencies": {
                "MyLibrary": "1.0.0-*"
            }
        },
        "dnxcore50": { }
    },
```

What should I do to my library to make it compatible to ASP.NET 5?

Comment: if you are not able to port the MyLibrary to dnxcore50 then you could remove dnxcore50 from your project.json and only use dnx451 aka desktop framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the libraries that your project depends on don't support `dotnetcore50` (CoreCLR) then you're out of luck. You need those to be ported first to CoreCLR before other CoreCLR libraries can use them.

Once you get a CoreCLR enabled dependency, you can add it to the top level `dependencies` node in `project.json` and then it will be available to all frameworks that your project supports.

Comment: Could you please hint me what is a typical way to port your class library to CoreCLR?

Comment: I guess this is create new asp.net class library project, setup frameworks to dnxcore50 and others, add sources, add dependencies, fix build errors if any, test and publish as local nuget package or publish to nuget.org, make a pull request if class lib is open source